# In ember.js what layer should the logic that handles a form submit and saves a record reside?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have made pretty good progress after a couple hours with rails-api, ember.js(rc-1.0), and ember-data. However, I am at a crossroads and need some advice. If I have a form that is used to create or update a record where should the submit action for this form be handled and persisted with ember-data.

I have seen examples that handle it in the router, the view, and the controller. I guess I do not yet have a clear understanding of what belongs where especially when views are involved. Should a view handle the submit action and delegate to the controller which in turn deals with the model? Views seem mostly optional and maybe I do not need one at all and can just delegate right to the controller if no view is involved.

Any additional thoughts on the responsibilities of each along with your preferred method would be much appreciated.

Comment: Model layer. In particular domain object (for validation) and data mappers (for storage).

Comment: That is what will be used to do the actual save, but where is the actual submit action of the form being handled? The click and then submission of the form. If the model is invalid, which layer should be rendering the errors?

Comment: Views should render errors. Controllers should handle actions, and sometimes it makes sense to let the router handle some of these actions. It really depends on what you're doing. You might want to check [this](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/Ember-Contact-Management-ConceptUI) as it addresses some of these questions, but keep in mind this is not "ready" and it's not connected to any backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an HTML `<form>` element, you'll need to catch the `submit` event in the view. You'll probably want the view to just tell the controller to save the model.

Another option would be to do something like this:

Save

The downside is that you don't get some of the benefits catching the `submit` event provides:

- HTML forms submit when you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- HTML5 forms won't submit if the validations/contraints aren't met